# Change default value of NA in heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

To plot a heatmap of the following input file the code below works fine and generates the image below

```
"people","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
"Ej1",0,0,0,1,0,1,1,NA,0
"Ej2",0,1,1,0,0,0,1,NA,0
"Ej3",0,1,1,1,0,0,0,NA,1
"Ej4",0,NA,0,0,NA,1,0,NA,1
"Ej5",1,0,1,1,0,1,1,NA,1
"Ej6",1,1,0,1,1,1,0,NA,0
"Ej7",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,NA,1
"Ej8",0,0,1,1,1,1,1,NA,0
"Ej9",1,1,0,0,1,0,0,NA,NA




library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(plyr)
data <- read.csv("fruits2.txt", head=TRUE, sep=",")
data$people <- factor(data$people,levels=rev(data$people))
data.m = melt(data,id='people')
data.m[,"rescale"]<-rescale(data.m[,"value"],to=c(0,1))
fewer.labels <- c("Ej9","Ej8","Ej7","Ej6","Ej5","Ej4","Ej3","Ej2","Ej1")
p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, people)) +
     geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") +
     scale_y_discrete(labels=fewer.labels) +
     scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8))
```

Now I'm trying to change the grey color of the NA values by another color, for example yellow, can't find where to set it.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scale_fill_gradient` supports the `na.value` parameter, which specifies the color to use for NA values (exactly what you want). So just change that line to:

```
scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", na.value="yellow")
```